# If I have network file sharing turned on, and I connect to a VPN, are my files then visible to other users on the VPN?

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, vpn, file-sharing

I have one computer on my home network that I always leave on, with a few shared folders set up so that other computers in my home network can access the files inside.

When I connect to a VPN, I'm essentially attaching that computer to another network run by the VPN company, right? Does that mean that other computers connected to that VPN then able to access my shared folders, or have access to my computer in any way, for that matter?

Comment: no a vpn just changes your ip and location not your network.

Comment: Mainly no but it depends on how the files are shared, your firewall settings and whether your VPN IP is known by other clients within the VPN. If your firewall is off and someone knows your VPN IP and you have "Everyone" allowed on the share then there is a small possibility they could access your shares. A VPN connection isn't like your Internet connection where your router providing NAT and the built-in firewall will prevent inbound connections. My work VPN, for example, if I join that then I can see my laptop from work when it's at home and vice versa.

Comment: Which computer are you connecting to the VPN? The computer with the shares? Or one of your network clients?

Comment: @BigChris One of the clients. Is there a difference if I connect a client to the VPN rather than the one with the shares set up?

Comment: You should be fairly safe because an intruder to your client would need to know the IP or hostname of the file server you're running, any credentials to access the shares and get past any firewall on your client.